# Remove header/footer on odd page

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, parallel

I'm compiling a bilingual document using the \parallel package, with headers and footers using the \fancyhdr package. I would like a couple of pages without header and footer to separate sections of the book, but even when using the \thispagestyle{empty} there is one page which does not remove the header and footer. I've even emptied the header for that page, but the line still appears.

Thank you in advance for any answers,
Carlos

```
\documentclass[openany,11pt]{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[autocompile]{gregoriotex}
\usepackage[papersize={6in,9in},top={15mm},headheight={10mm},headsep={5mm},left={17.5mm},right={17.5mm},bottom={15mm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{parallel}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tipa}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhead[CO]{{\color{red}Ordinario}}
\fancyhead[CE]{{\color{red}Ordinarium}}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[C,R,L]{}

\begin{document}
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}

\vspace*{\fill}

\begin{center}
\textsc{\huge{El Oficio de Completas}}
\end{center}

\vspace*{\fill}

\begin{Parallel}[p]{}{}

\ParallelPar

\ParallelLText{
\normalsize{\textit{\color{red}Ab Festa Sanctisimmæ Trinitatis ad feria sexta ante primam domenicam adventi}} 
\vspace{3mm}
\gregorioscore{salvesolemne}
\vspace*{\fill}
}

\ParallelRText{
\normalsize{\textit{\color{red}Desde las I Vísperas de la fiesta de la Santísima Trinidad hasta el viernes antes del primer domingo de Adviento}} 
\vspace{3mm}
\gregorioscore{salvesimple}
\vspace*{\fill}
\small{
Dios te salve, Reina y Madre de misericordia, 
vida, dulzura y esperanza nuestra. 
Dios te salve. 
A Ti clamamos los desterrados hijos de Eva, 
a Ti suspiramos, gimiendo y llorando en este valle de lágrimas. 
Ea, pues, Señora Abogada Nuestra, 
vuelve a nosotros tus ojos misericordiosos, 
y después de este destierro, muéstranos a Jesús,
fruto bendito de tu vientre.
Oh, clemente, oh piadosa, oh dulce Virgen María. }
\vspace*{\fill}
}

\ParallelPar

\fancyhead[CO]{}
\fancyhead[CE]{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{}

\ParallelLText{
\thispagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{center}
\textsc{\huge{Psalterium}}
\end{center}
\vspace*{\fill}
}

%%This is the problematic page
\ParallelRText{
\thispagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{center}
\textsc{\huge{Salterio}}
\end{center}
\vspace*{\fill}
}

\ParallelPar

\fancyhead[CE]{{\color{red}Post I Vesperas Domenicæ}}
\fancyhead[CO]{{\color{red}Después de las I Vísperas del Domingo}}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}

\ParallelLText{
\begin{center}
\textsc{\Large{Post I Vesperas Domenicæ et Solemnitatum}}
\end{center}
\normalsize{\textit{\color{red}Omnia ut in Ordinario,}} p.2{\textit{\color{red}, praeter sequentia : }}
\vspace*{\fill}
}

\ParallelRText{
\begin{center}
\textsc{\Large{Después de las I Vísperas del Domingo y de las Solemnidades}}
\end{center}
\normalsize{\textit{\color{red}Todo como en el Ordinario,}} p.3{\textit{\color{red}, excepto lo siguiente : }}
\vspace*{\fill}
}

\end{Parallel}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This may be an inherent limitation of fancyhdr.  There are other ways to customize headers and footers.